# Opening a document by clicking on menu entries in spreadsheet (google apps script)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've written a script (google apps script) : it works with a spreadsheet (with menu entries and several functions...) and it's ok.
The problem is: I want to show a sort of help file for the user of that spreadsheet.
The format can be pdf or doc, I don't care... 
But I don't know how to open this "help file" by clicking on a menu entry.
I've tried with something like:

```
function help(){
 var doc = documentApp.openByUrl("url of may help file, present in my google drive");
}
```

My help file is shared but it doesn't work!
Sorry for this message... I'm french and my English is bad!

Answer (score 1):

Your best option will be to include the help file as an `html` file within your spreadsheet script. This ensures that it is maintained along with the spreadsheet script, simplifying management of it.

Here's an example:

[image: Screenshot]

To implement this, follow the examples provided in the documentation for the [HtmlService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html-service#serve_html_as_a_google_docs_sheets_or_forms_user_interface).

### Code.gs

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

function onOpen() {
  var menu = [{name: 'Spreadsheet Help', functionName: 'openHelp'}];
  ss.addMenu('Custom', menu);
}

function openHelp() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('help');
  ss.show(html);
}
```

### help.html

```
<div>
<H1>Help File</H1>
<P>
This is a simple help file. Not much to it.
<P>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent iaculis leo vitae sollicitudin vulputate. Donec pretium semper nibh. Suspendisse mollis dolor imperdiet, tincidunt arcu eu, egestas nibh. Aliquam tempor consectetur turpis, quis placerat ligula tristique a. Cras nibh velit, hendrerit id sollicitudin non, malesuada at justo. Cras nec ipsum at massa tempor cursus. Aliquam et pretium mauris, sed posuere urna. Cras risus ligula, lacinia eu tortor eu, mattis fermentum dolor. Proin id turpis justo. Praesent et nulla tempor, tristique felis sit amet, pretium dolor. Mauris suscipit feugiat dapibus. Ut sit amet est vel risus vulputate placerat.
<P>
Sed bibendum tortor sed ligula ultrices mollis. Aenean purus sem, tincidunt ac lectus sed, posuere semper dolor. Etiam quis porttitor magna, eu adipiscing metus. Nullam eget varius elit, in fermentum purus. Maecenas bibendum fermentum est, vitae aliquam ligula eleifend porttitor. Phasellus sollicitudin justo nibh, vitae placerat justo fermentum iaculis. Pellentesque sagittis, lacus et pulvinar laoreet, felis tortor vulputate lectus, et ultrices velit neque sed turpis. Nunc fringilla quis mi at scelerisque. Donec vitae eleifend erat. Suspendisse tellus orci, fringilla quis tellus ac, adipiscing blandit nibh. Maecenas tincidunt auctor viverra. Quisque commodo, purus eu tincidunt luctus, lacus leo fringilla odio, vel tempus leo felis at enim. Nunc ut gravida est. Nam fringilla odio elit, in gravida lacus dapibus eu.
<P>
Nam vehicula ultrices dolor, cursus cursus quam congue sit amet. Vestibulum vehicula, nisl non ornare tincidunt, nisl lorem accumsan sapien, eu porttitor lacus mauris ac magna. Vivamus sed eleifend lorem. Cras eu ipsum at nunc feugiat feugiat quis quis quam. Aenean eleifend urna vitae orci pharetra porttitor. Aenean tempor pulvinar orci id tempor. Nam facilisis eleifend tempus. Suspendisse adipiscing diam nec fermentum ullamcorper. Integer varius convallis eros sed accumsan. Vestibulum condimentum, tortor at ullamcorper scelerisque, lectus velit posuere ligula, sed consequat velit mauris quis ligula. Nam fermentum tempus gravida. In mollis neque non varius accumsan. Nunc condimentum, eros eu viverra cursus, libero massa mattis erat, in elementum libero lectus non nisi. Curabitur varius facilisis erat, vitae feugiat erat. Donec nunc mauris, ultricies ut sodales eu, commodo at arcu.
<P>
Curabitur eget semper lacus. Mauris nec sodales magna. Vivamus vulputate lorem et ornare pharetra. Donec metus elit, malesuada nec massa sit amet, aliquet imperdiet nisl. Morbi vitae tempus purus, quis gravida dui. Proin facilisis eros sit amet odio rhoncus molestie. Phasellus vel dolor sed mi sagittis accumsan. Donec velit ante, varius at faucibus quis, porttitor pretium nisl. Maecenas tempor hendrerit volutpat. Vivamus congue mauris id mattis ullamcorper.
<P>
Proin dignissim metus vitae tellus tristique tempus. Aliquam at imperdiet lacus. Quisque sed adipiscing libero. Ut tincidunt mauris quis placerat ultricies. Sed quis congue massa. Maecenas ac lectus ac augue feugiat euismod ut vel orci. Praesent sapien turpis, elementum vitae dignissim tincidunt, dignissim gravida justo. Vivamus bibendum eu lorem eget porta. Donec tincidunt malesuada urna vitae porttitor. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nam sodales justo at massa egestas, ut hendrerit purus ultricies. Sed id ultricies erat, eget convallis nisl. Sed blandit, metus sit amet vehicula rutrum, lorem massa pulvinar enim, vel mollis turpis nisi a nulla. Curabitur lacinia nibh non accumsan sollicitudin. Pellentesque eget nunc luctus, fringilla arcu id, mattis tortor. Maecenas egestas, felis vestibulum tincidunt gravida, quam odio dictum velit, ac volutpat mi mauris eget massa.
</div>
```